# Isolated power supplies - Would this work the way it is depicted in the schematic?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, isolation

Would current be able to flow without noise/interference if the power supplies were isolated i.e. had separate return paths?

[image]

Comment: The short answer is no, as per your other question.

Comment: Can you explain why? Will the GND_PRI interfere some how with the 30V_SEC?

Edit: so what would happen?

Comment: You have shorted both isolated power supplies, and connected them with a resistor. Only the currents caused by common mode noise/interference would flow through the resistor and affect the potential between supplies. So it depends on the supplies. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Okay, I just made a similar post about how using two separate grounds (return paths) did not result in any current flowing. Why would this configuration cause any current to flow?

Comment: You’ve connected two power supplies reverse-wired to each other; consider 30V_sec connected to GND_pri; this gives you a combined 60V between 30V_pri and GND_sec but you then wire the two together.  This will result in a large current flowing as you’ve shorted the supply.  If the two supplies have identical current capability then they will both be trying to push current in opposite directions through the resistor and the net current in the resistor will be zero.

Answer (score 4):

This is the circuit you have drawn.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frcHTH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Compare it against:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5DSAH.png)</sup>

See the short-circuit?

Comment: Someone asking this question might answer the last question with 'no'. So you should be more explicit.

Comment: @tobalt That thought did occur to me, which is why I ended up adding the second schematic.

Comment: And even that just poses a rhetorical question. You should tell *why* that is a problem, considering the apparent experience of the asker and the small chance of a burning house.

Comment: Fine. I edited it.

Comment: @RGBEngineer I suggest you do indeed click the *"simulate this circuit"*.